# Prove the generalized version of Euler's totient function.If $(a,b)=d$, then $\varphi(ab) = {d\varphi(a)\varphi(b)\over \varphi(d)}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

If $(a,b)=d$, then $$\varphi(ab) = {d\varphi(a)\varphi(b)\over \varphi(d)}$$

I thought about writing out $a, b$ and $d$ in their prime power decomposition, but then wasn't sure how to proceed.

Comment: Start by considering the case that $a$ and $b$ are both powers of the same prime $p$ (possibly $p^0$).

Comment: good tip! I was able to prove it for a=p^k and b=p^r. Now, to try to generalize it....

Comment: Given the prime decompositions of $a$ and $b$, do you know the formulas for [$d=(a,b)$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor#Using_prime_factorizations) and [$\phi(a)$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function#Computing_Euler.27s_function), $\phi(b)$, $\phi(d)$, and $\phi(ab)$?

Comment: I figured it out! Thanks all :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start from the product form for totient
$$
\varphi(a) = a \prod_{p\setminus a}\left( 1-\frac1p \right)
$$
where the notation $\prod_{p\setminus a}$ means the product over all primes $p$ that divide $a$.
Then
$$
\varphi(a) \varphi(b)= a \prod_{p\setminus a}\left( 1-\frac1p \right)b \prod_{q\setminus a}\left( 1-\frac1q \right)
$$
where in the second product I use $q$ as the dummy variable to stand for a prime, just to avoid confusion of two $p$'s in the formula.

Again applying the formula, this time to $ab$, we have
$$
\varphi(ab) = ab \prod_{p\setminus (ab)}\left( 1-\frac1p \right)
$$
Now the key step:  If $p\setminus (ab)$ then either $p\setminus a$ or $p\setminus b$ or both.  So if we were to decompose the produce into two products  the products $ \prod_{p\setminus a}(1-1/p) \prod_{q\setminus b}(1-1/q)$ we will have double-counted (actually, multiplied twice by) any term associated with a prime $r$ that divides both $a$ and $b$.  Thus
$$
\varphi(ab) = \frac{ ab \prod_{p\setminus a}(1-\frac1p)
\prod_{q\setminus b}\left( 1-\frac1q \right) }{\prod_{r\setminus a \wedge r\setminus b}\left( 1-\frac1r \right)}
$$
But  $r\setminus a \wedge r\setminus b$ if and only if $r\setminus d$ where $d$ is the g.c.d. of $a$ and $b$.  Using that we have
$$
\varphi(ab) = \frac{ ab \prod_{p\setminus a}(1-\frac1p)
\prod_{q\setminus b}\left( 1-\frac1q \right) }{\prod_{r\setminus d}\left( 1-\frac1r \right)}
$$ and since 
$$ \varphi(d) = d\prod_{r\setminus d}\left( 1-\frac1r \right) \implies 
\prod_{r\setminus d}\left( 1-\frac1r \right) = \frac{\varphi(d)}{d}
$$
we can substitute for the denominator to get
$$
\varphi(ab) =  a \prod_{p\setminus a}(1-\frac1p)
b\prod_{q\setminus b}\left( 1-\frac1q \right) \frac{d}{\varphi(d)} = 
\varphi(a) \varphi(b) \frac{d}{\varphi(d)}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Here's a "cute" way to see this using the related function $F(n) := \phi(n)/n$, which enjoys the simple property that $F(n) = \prod_{p \mid n} F(p)$, so that $F(n)$ is determined precisely by the set of primes dividing $n$ (and is independent of the *exponents* of those primes).

In particular, taking the additive function  $f(n) := -\log F(n)$, we can view $f$ as a point measure on the set of primes.  Specifically, taking the mass $\mu(\{p\}) := f(p)$ at each prime $p$, we have $f(n) = \mu(\mathcal P(n))$ where $\mathcal P(n) := \{ p : p \mid n\}$ is the set of primes dividing $n$.

Rephrasing in terms of $f$, the claim in the question reduces to $F(ab) F(d) = F(a)F(b)$, or $f(ab) + f(d) = f(a) + f(b)$.  But this follows easily from the "Venn diagram" identity $\mu(A\cup B) + \mu(A\cap B) = \mu(A) + \mu(B)$, upon observing that $\mathcal P(ab) = \mathcal P(a) \cup \mathcal P(b)$ and $\mathcal P(d) = \mathcal P(a) \cap \mathcal P(b)$.